# Equivalent of C# anonymous methods in Java?

Tags: java, c#, delegates, processing, anonymous-function

In C# you can define delegates anonymously (even though they are nothing more than syntactic sugar). For example, I can do this:

```
public string DoSomething(Func<string, string> someDelegate)
{
     // Do something involving someDelegate(string s)
} 

DoSomething(delegate(string s){ return s += "asd"; });
DoSomething(delegate(string s){ return s.Reverse(); });
```

Is it possible to pass code like this in Java? I'm using the processing framework, which has a quite old version of Java (it doesn't have generics).

Comment: [A q on delegates in general in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912/java-delegates)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**Pre Java 8:**

The closest Java has to delegates are single method interfaces. You could use an anonymous inner class.

```
interface StringFunc {
   String func(String s);
}

void doSomething(StringFunc funk) {
   System.out.println(funk.func("whatever"));
}

doSomething(new StringFunc() {
      public String func(String s) {
           return s + "asd";
      }
   });


doSomething(new StringFunc() {
      public String func(String s) {
           return new StringBuffer(s).reverse().toString();
      }
   });
```

---

**Java 8 and above:**

[Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) adds lambda expressions to the language.

```
    doSomething((t) -> t + "asd");
    doSomething((t) -> new StringBuilder(t).reverse().toString());
```

Comment: [Google Collections][1] and Groovy[2] might be of interest to you.

[1] http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/
[2] http://groovy.codehaus.org/

Answer (score 13):

Not exactly like this but Java has something similar.

It's called anonymous inner classes.

Let me give you an example:

```
DoSomething(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
       // "delegate" body
   }
});
```

It's a little more verbose and requires an interface to implement,
but other than that it's pretty much the same thing

Answer (score 4):

Your example would look like this in Java, using anomymous inner classes:

```
interface Func {
    String execute(String s);
}

public String doSomething(Func someDelegate) {
    // Do something involving someDelegate.execute(String s)
}

doSomething(new Func() { public String execute(String s) { return s + "asd"; } });
doSomething(new Func() { public String execute(String s) { return new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString(); } } });
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to pass code like this
>   in Java? I'm using the processing
>   framework, which has a quite old
>   version of Java (it doesn't have
>   generics).

Since the question asked about the Processing-specific answer, there is no direct equivalent. But Processing uses the Java 1.4 language level, and Java 1.1 introduced anonymous inner classes, which are a rough approximation.

Answer (score 3):

For example :

```
public class Delegate
{
    interface Func
    {
        void execute(String s);
    }

    public static void doSomething(Func someDelegate) {
        someDelegate.execute("123");
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {

        Func someFuncImplementation = new Func() 
        {
            @Override
            public void execute(String s) {
                System.out.println("Bla Bla :"  + s);
            }
        };

        Func someOtherFuncImplementation = new Func() 
        {
            @Override
            public void execute(String s) {
                System.out.println("Foo Bar:"  + s);
            }
        };


        doSomething(someFuncImplementation);
        doSomething(someOtherFuncImplementation);
    }
}
```

Output :

> Bla Bla :123
>
> Foo Bar:123

Answer (score 0):

You have all forgotten here that a C# delegate first of all - is **thread safe**.
These examples are just for a single thread App..

Most of the contemporary Apps are written on multithreaded concept..
So no one answer is the answer.

There is not an equivalent in Java

Comment: It isn't that what you are saying is wrong. It's correct. The problem is, this does not actually answer the question being asked---it just says all the other answers are wrong. Are you saying that there is *not* an equivalent in Java?

Comment: The difference here would for most users be small. I'd even argue that the lack of multicast is a bigger difference between the two.

As far as the question is phrased I believe the answers above are correct. All are clear that they are talking about the closest Java has.

Comment: As references are atomic, the Java version will not crash, but you could have stale data. To make it thread safe all you need to do is add the keyword "volatile".