# How to set method name as a parameter in a new class?

Tags: java, android, class, methods, parameters

I have created a AlertDialog class that has a method called `OnYesClicked()` which will be called when the positive button is clicked. However, I need to use this AlertDialog class more than once in the same activity, so I want to set the name `OnYesClicked()` as a parameter, so that I can call the correct method for different dialogs, or else the wrong method or both methods may be called. I am not too sure on how to solve this problem after searching up other similar questions including one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616796/how-do-i-pass-method-as-a-parameter-in-java)
The full code is below:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDialogFragment;

public class ExampleDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

    private static final String ARGUMENT_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String ARGUMENT_POSITIVE = "positive";
    private static final String ARGUMENT_MESSAGE = "message";
    private static final String ARGUMENT_POSITIVE_TEXT = "positive_text";
    private static final String ARGUMENT_NEGATIVE = "negative";
    private static final String ARGUMENT_NEGATIVE_TEXT = "negative_text";

    private ExampleDialogListener listener;

    private String title;
    private String message;
    private String positive;
    private String positivetext;
    private String negative;
    private  String negativetext;

    public static ExampleDialog newInstance(String title, String message, String positive,//request input from user when call, save as string
                                            String positivetext, String negative, String negativetext) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        // Store all arguments into bundle.
        args.putString(ARGUMENT_TITLE, title); //save as name ARGUMENT_TITLE, value is the user input title, shove inside a bundle called args
        args.putString(ARGUMENT_POSITIVE, positive);
        args.putString(ARGUMENT_MESSAGE, message);
        args.putString(ARGUMENT_POSITIVE_TEXT, positivetext);
        args.putString(ARGUMENT_NEGATIVE, negative);
        args.putString(ARGUMENT_NEGATIVE_TEXT, negativetext);
        ExampleDialog fragment = new ExampleDialog();
        fragment.setArguments(args); //put whole bundle into fragment
        return fragment; //fragment is given to code that call this newInstance
    }


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)  {

        title = getArguments().getString(ARGUMENT_TITLE); //using key, retrieve string value (user input), set as "title"
        positive = getArguments().getString(ARGUMENT_POSITIVE);
        message = getArguments().getString(ARGUMENT_MESSAGE);
        positivetext = getArguments().getString(ARGUMENT_POSITIVE_TEXT);
        negative = getArguments().getString(ARGUMENT_NEGATIVE);
        negativetext = getArguments().getString(ARGUMENT_NEGATIVE);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setNegativeButton(negative, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), negativetext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton(positive, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), positivetext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                        listener.onYesClicked(); //listens for method onYesClicked(), need declare in code when call this class
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }

    public interface ExampleDialogListener {
        void onYesClicked();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        try {
            listener = (ExampleDialogListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                    + "must implement ExampleDialogListener");
        }
    }
}
```

when using the class, I need to also call the following

```
  public void openDialog() {
          ExampleDialog dialog = ExampleDialog.newInstance("Title", "message",
                                                      "positive","positive text",
                                                      "negative","negative text");
          dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"example dialog");}
 @Override
 public void onYesClicked() {
    //what happens if yes is clicked
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the definition of your callback method to include a tag as a parameter. Each time you call the method use a different tag to identify the dialog you’re using it from. Inside the implementation of the callback create a switch to identify where the callback is coming from and do what needs to be done accordingly.

Definition:

```
public interface ExampleDialogListener {
        void onYesClicked(String tag);
    }
```

Trigger:

```
listener.onYesClicked("dialogA");
```

Implementation:

```
@Override
 public void onYesClicked(String tag) {
    //what happens if yes is clicked
    Switch (tag) {
        case “dialogA”:
            //method for dialog A
        break;
        case “dialogB”:
            //method for dialog B
        break;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the listener in the `onAttach()` of `ExampleDialog`, pass the instance of `ExampleDialogListener` from outside. Maintain different listeners instances of `ExampleDialogListener` in an activity, which will give you control to callbacks of individual `ExampleDialog`.

Like this:

STEP 1: Remove the statement that sets the `ExampleDialogListener` in the `onAttach()` of `ExampleDialog`

```
@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    /*try {
        listener = (ExampleDialogListener) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                + "must implement ExampleDialogListener");
    }*/
}
```

STEP 2: Add a `public` Method in the `ExampleFragment` that initializes the `ExampleDialogListener`.

```
public void setListener(ExampleDialogListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

STEP 3: Pass the instance of `ExampleDialogListener` in the method `newInstance()` and set the listener there.

```
public static ExampleDialog newInstance(
    String title,
    String message,
    String positive,
    String positivetext,
    String negative,
    String negativetext,
    ExampleDialogListener listener /* Pass the Listener from outside */
) {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    args.putString(ARGUMENT_TITLE, title);
    args.putString(ARGUMENT_POSITIVE, positive);
    args.putString(ARGUMENT_MESSAGE, message);
    args.putString(ARGUMENT_POSITIVE_TEXT, positivetext);
    args.putString(ARGUMENT_NEGATIVE, negative);
    args.putString(ARGUMENT_NEGATIVE_TEXT, negativetext);

    ExampleDialog fragment = new ExampleDialog();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    fragment.setListener(listener); // <---- SET THE LISTENER HERE

    return fragment;

}
```

STEP 4: Create the multiple instances of `ExampleDialogListener`.

```
private ExampleDialog.ExampleDialogListener listener1 = new ExampleDialog.ExampleDialogListener() {
    @Override
    public void onYesClicked() {
        // Your Implementation
    }
};

private ExampleDialog.ExampleDialogListener listener2 = new ExampleDialog.ExampleDialogListener() {
    @Override
    public void onYesClicked() {
        // Your Implementation
    }
};

private ExampleDialog.ExampleDialogListener listener3 = new ExampleDialog.ExampleDialogListener() {
    @Override
    public void onYesClicked() {
        // Your Implementation
    }
};
```

Finally, set different listeners to each `ExampleDialog`.

```
public void openDialog() {
    ExampleDialog dialog1 = ExampleDialog.newInstance(
        "Title",
        "message",
        "positive",
        "positive text",
        "negative",
        "negative text",
        listener1
    );

    ExampleDialog dialog2 = ExampleDialog.newInstance(
        "Title",
        "message",
        "positive",
        "positive text",
        "negative",
        "negative text",
        listener2
    );

    ExampleDialog dialog3 = ExampleDialog.newInstance(
        "Title",
        "message",
        "positive",
        "positive text",
        "negative",
        "negative text",
        listener3
    );

    dialog1.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"example dialog");
    dialog2.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"example dialog");
    dialog3.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"example dialog");
}
```