# java: local variable looper is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final, but then variable might not have been initialized

Tags: java, variables, interface, parameters, scope

I'm using something a bit like the [command pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2186993/2770572) to create a class which implements a simple interface for a method I reuse frequently, but in different ways.

I was able to get it working using a couple different methods, but I prefer this one, courtesy of Jon Skeet.

```
public class InterfaceProblemExample implements Runnable{

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new InterfaceProblemExample().run();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int dim = 3;
        final double[][] oldMatrix = new double[dim][dim];
        final double[][] newMatrix = new double[dim][dim];

        final AtomicReference<Looper> wrapper = new AtomicReference<Looper>();
        Looper looper = new Looper(dim, new Commandable() {
            @Override
            public void execute() {
                int axis1 = wrapper.get().getiAxis1();
                int axis2 = wrapper.get().getiAxis2();
                newMatrix[axis1][axis2] = oldMatrix[axis1][axis2] + 2.5;
            }
        });
        wrapper.set(looper);
        looper.execute();
    }

    public interface Commandable {
        public abstract void execute();
    }

    public class Looper implements Commandable {

        private Commandable command;
        private int iAxis1;
        private int iAxis2;
        private int dim;

        public Looper(int dim, Commandable command) {
            this.command = command;
            this.dim = dim;
        }

        public void setCommand(Commandable command) {
            this.command = command;
        }

        @Override
        public void execute() {
            for (iAxis2 = 1; iAxis2 < dim; iAxis2++) {
                for (iAxis1 = 0; iAxis1 < iAxis2; iAxis1++) {
                    command.execute();
                }
            }
        }

        public int getiAxis1() {
            return iAxis1;
        }

        public int getiAxis2() {
            return iAxis2;
        }

        public int getDim() {
            return dim;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should include what language / platform this is, many people might skip answering this just because of that ambiguity since there many languages that look similar these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've effectively got a cyclic dependency: your `Looper` needs to be initialized with the `Commandable`, and the `Commandable` needs to be initialized with the `Looper`. The compiler is absolutely right to complain - imagine if the `Looper` constructor called `command.execute()` - that would try to use the `looper` variable (within the anonymous inner class) before you initialize it.

You need to break that cycle. For example:

- You could make the `Looper` have a `setCommandable` method
- You could make your `Commandable` implementation have a `setLooper` method
- You could pass the `Looper` into the `execute` method

As a really hacky way round this, you could use an array or an atomic reference as a "wrapper":

```
public void run() {
    final AtomicReference<Looper> wrapper = new AtomicReference<Looper>();
    Looper looper = new Looper(new Commandable() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            System.out.println("This is easy: ");
            System.out.println("This isn't easy: " + wrapper.get().getI());
        }
    });
    wrapper.set(looper);
    looper.execute();
}
```

But that's pretty nasty.

Comment: Your first two answers made perfect sense, and fixed my problem immediately.

Comment: I don't get how the third one would be implemented, but that last one is amazing to look at. Thanks so much for that Jon. This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. I'm going to have a lot of fun trying to understand this

Comment: @doctordoder: The third approach would need `Commandable` to be changed. For example, it could be generic in the type of object it needs to work on. Let me know if you want the array equivalent of the last one instead.

Comment: If you give me 5 minutes, I'll show you what exactly I'm needing.

Comment: Alright, I'm locked out of GitHub for some reason, but I edited the original question to include a version of what I'm actually trying to do.

Comment: @doctordoder: I suggest you revert the question, as now it's got *working* code which claims not to work. So long as the answer has helped you, that's probably all we need :) Let me know if there's anything more you need though.