# Giving the parameter System.out::println to a method

Tags: java

I forgot a concept that I used and can't remember it.

For the context, I used to have a method like `toString()` which had a parameter. This parameters allowed me to call my method like `myMethod(System.out::println)` to print it on the screen, but also to print it in a file with the same syntax.

Does anyone know what can be this parameter? the concept?
I think it's kind of a *FunctionalInterface* but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Do you want to write what you send to ```System.out.println()```to a file? Or did I get you wrong

Comment: Post some of your codes.

Comment: Actually i don't have a code ^^ but it will be like a predicate i think. For exemple i give "System.out.println" to "myMethod", and myMethod" use the println with a local String.

Comment: You're probably talking about a [PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out)

Comment: Take a look at [this (Command Pattern)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186931/java-pass-method-as-parameter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called method reference and applies when you know what method you want to call, provided the method already exist.

[From the tutorial :](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

> Because this lambda expression invokes an existing method, you can use
>   a method reference instead of a lambda expression:
>
> Arrays.sort(rosterAsArray, Person::compareByAge);

Available since Java-8.

An exemple using what you want:

```
    public static void function(String s, Consumer<String> f) {
    f.accept(s);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String test1 = "test";
    String test2 = "test2";
    function(test1, System.out::println);
    function(test2, System.out::println);
    function(test1, System.out::print);
    function(test2, System.out::print);
}
```

Comment: Yes that's what I'm searching for. In the tutorial, it's used with a "Comparator" that will provide the compare method. What i want to know is how to find this provider for other method. In my previous example, I'm searching for the "println" provider.

Comment: +1 for using `Consumer<String>` (wanter to alert that `Consumer<? extends String>` would be better, but String is final class :3)

Comment: The use of the function(String, Consumer<String>) is how i want it. But does the Comsumer.accept trigger the println method?

Comment: yes, per the javadoc : accept(T t) `Performs this operation on the given argument.`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I caon't try it for now, but it realy helps. Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
public class C {
  static void myMethod(java.io.PrintStream p) {
    p.println("Hello!");
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    myMethod(System.out);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately you can't pass `System.out.println` directly, because in Java methods (before Java 8) are not first-class objects. All you can do with a method is calling it. As a workaround, you can introduce an interface and create an adapter class.

Comment: Since Java8 we can pass method to directly. We can pass a "lambda", it's a method that we created in our code (for example, we can give a method run directly to a Thread instead of creating the Runnable before). But we can pass existing methods, and th'ats what i'm looking for. CédricC is on the right way with his respons : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24303031/3755297

Answer (score 0):

This goes well with java 8 functional interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
static interface MyPrinter {
    public void println(String line);
}

static void myMethod(MyPrinter mp) {
    mp.println("Hello wolrd");
}

...

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    myMethod(System.out::println);

    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("myFile.txt");
    myMethod(pw::println);
    pw.close(); //never forget to close file output streams!

    //EDIT: note that you can of course store your MyPrinter in a variable:
    MyPrinter mp = System.err::println;
    myMethod(mp);
}
```

Comment: A bit like that. But in my memories, it didn't need to create a functionnal interface as the println method was already existing.