# An elegant way of saying if not null then use this setter method in Java 6?

Tags: java

I'm writing a custom deserializer for some json like data in my workplace, I have to set many values via setter methods and I want to only do that if they're not null.

Is there a nice way I can do this in Java by maybe passing the setter function as a parameter to another method?

i.e. Psuedo code:

```
private void setValue(Func setterMethod, <T> value){
    if (value != null){
        setterMethod(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Pass Method as Parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186931/java-pass-method-as-parameter)

Comment: Not in a way that will not make your code a lot more unreadable. If you are deserializing by iterating through a map, why not check first if the value is not null, then make the decision which method to call?

Answer (score 6):

If your setter is a proper setter with returns void you must use a Consumer instead of a Function. This can only be used since Java 8.

```
private <T> void updateValue(Consumer<T> setterMethod, T value) {
    if (value != null){
        setterMethod.accept(value);
    }
}
```

This is usefull for partial updates. Example of use:

```
public Person partialUpdate(UUID id, Person update) {
    Person original = getPersonById(id);
    updateValue(original::setName, update.getName());
    updateValue(original::setAge, update.getAge());
    updateValue(original::setAddress, update.getAddress());
    return original;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using generic it's not clear what is the domain of the function,
 but assuming it's  `T -> T` you can do something like:

```
private <T> void setValue(Function<T, T> setterMethod, T value){
    if (value != null){
        setterMethod.apply(value);
    }
}
```

That said, Java 6 does *not* supports it (Java 8 does).

Answer (score 0):

in java 6 you can define an interface like this

```
public interface Setter<T> {
    void set(T value);
}
```

and then implement your method this way

```
private <T> void setValue(Setter<T> setterMethod, T value){
    if (value != null){
        setterMethod.set(value);
    } 
}
```