# How to put an alert dialog in another class inside a function

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Guys i've created a custom `date and time picker` in my app now i'm using that `picker` several times . So, for avoiding the redundancy of code I thought i should put that function inside a separate function in another class from where i can  call that whenever i need that but i'm not able to do so, Please help.
The separate class is :

```
public class DateTimePicker {
    String str;

    public String returnDate(final Context ctx) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
        final DatePicker picker1 = new DatePicker(ctx);

        try {
            Field f[] = picker1.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field field : f) {
                if (field.getName().equals("mYearPicker")|| field.getName().equals("mYearSpinner") ) {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    Object yearPicker = new Object();
                    yearPicker = field.get(picker1);
                    ((View) yearPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        picker1.setCalendarViewShown(false);

        builder1.setTitle("Please select date on which you would be leaving :")
            .setView(picker1)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd MMM");
                    Date date1 = new Date();
                    date1.setDate(picker1.getDayOfMonth());
                    date1.setMonth(picker1.getMonth());
                    final String s = parseFormat.format(date1);
                    Log.e("DATE",s);

                    //Time picker
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
                    final TimePicker picker = new TimePicker(ctx);
                    picker.setIs24HourView(true);
                    builder.setTitle("Please select time at which you would be leaving :")
                        .setView(picker)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                int hour = picker.getCurrentHour();
                                int minute = picker.getCurrentMinute();
                                str = s + " " + hour + ":" + minute;
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("One way", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }).create().show();
                        //Time picker
                    }
                }
            )
            .setNegativeButton("One way", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .create().show();

        return "hello "+ str ;
    }
```

and the code from where i'm using the above class is :

```
DateTimePicker obj = new DateTimePicker();
Log.e("Object", "Created");
String st = obj.returnDate(this.getActivity());
Log.e("Function", "Called");
System.out.println("Value returned :" + st);
leaving.setText(st);
```

On log i'm getting "**hello null**" evething gets printed as soon as i called the function it is not even waiting for user input.
please help thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will always get "hello null" back because the dialog internally creates a new thread and the answer of the dialog is only available in the respective button click listeners.

What you can do is to give a `callback` method to the function that creates the dialog and call this method once you have the answer in the dialog.

For inplementation details on how to pass a function as parameter see [Java Pass Method as Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186931/java-pass-method-as-parameter).

**edit**

On second thought, it is much more elegant to send the `onClickListeners` as the parameters of your dialog function.

You can define the onclick for all three last buttons in your flow like

```
DialogInterface.OnClickListener
     yesButton = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    int hour = picker.getCurrentHour();
                    int minute = picker.getCurrentMinute();
                    str = s + " " + hour + ":" + minute;
                     SomeFunction();
            }
        });
```

And pass 3 of these objects to your dialog function that than needs a function header like

```
public void returnDate(final Context ctx, OnClickListener yes, OnClickListener no1, OnClickListener no2) {
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call show() the code won't stop and wait for a user input. Try adding:

```
[...]
}).create().show();
Log.i("Dialog", "Show called");
```

to understand what happens.

If you want to use the input data from your Dialog you have to call a function from within you positive button listener:

```
.setPositiveButton("OK",
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        int hour=picker.getCurrentHour();
        int minute=picker.getCurrentMinute();

        sendToSomewhere("+hour+":"+minute");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should define the method returning void. And to accept the user input String, you can use **callback**.

- Get OnUserInputListener as a constructor arugment (though you can get it other way)
- Define interface in the `DateTimePicker` class.

Your `DateTimePicker` class will be like below:

```
public class DateTimePicker {
    private final OnUserInputListener onUserInputListener;

    // String str; <-- this field value has no use

    DateTimePicker(OnUserInputListener onUserInputListener) {
        this.onUserInputListener = onUserInputListener;
    }

    public void returnDate(final Context ctx) {

        ...

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            int hour = picker.getCurrentHour();
            int minute = picker.getCurrentMinute();
            str = s + " " + hour + ":" + minute;
            onUserInputListener.onUserInput(str); // CALL BACK!!!
        }

        ...

    }

    public interface OnUserInputListener {
        void onUserInput(String string);
    }
}
```

For the caller side class, it should implement OnUserInputListener.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnUserInputListener {

    ...

    DateTimePicker obj = new DateTimePicker(this);
    obj.returnDate(this.getActivity());

    ...

    @override
    public void onUserInput(String string) {
        System.out.println("Value returned :" + string);
        leaving.setText(string);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable responses. Now i'll try these  Answers

Answer (score 0):

This may help you!

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    TextView textView, tv;

    public DatePickerFragment(TextView textView, TextView text) {
        this.textView = textView;
        tv = text;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
        String dateForButton = dateFormat.format(mCalendar.getTime());
        textView.setText(dateForButton);
        tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

and for show dialog

```
dateFragment = new DatePickerFragment(toDate, tvTo);
dateFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Dialog Title");
```

you can use it in activity/ custom class

Answer (score 0):

Try to add custom date selected listener in DateTimePicker :

```
public interface OnDateSelectedListener{
  public void onDateSelected(String date);
}
```

Add custom interface inside DateTimePicker and set listener reference returnDate :

```
public class DateTimePicker {

    public void returnDate(final Context ctx, final OnDateSelectedListener onDateSelectedListener) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
        final DatePicker picker1 = new DatePicker(ctx);

        try {
            Field f[] = picker1.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field field : f) {
                if (field.getName().equals("mYearPicker") || field.getName().equals("mYearSpinner")) {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    Object yearPicker = new Object();
                    yearPicker = field.get(picker1);
                    ((View) yearPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        picker1.setCalendarViewShown(false);

        builder1.setTitle("Please select date on which you would be leaving :")
                .setView(picker1)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd MMM");
                                Date date1 = new Date();
                                date1.setDate(picker1.getDayOfMonth());
                                date1.setMonth(picker1.getMonth());
                                final String s = parseFormat.format(date1);
                                Log.e("DATE", s);

                                //Time picker
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
                                final TimePicker picker = new TimePicker(ctx);
                                picker.setIs24HourView(true);
                                builder.setTitle("Please select time at which you would be leaving :")
                                        .setView(picker)
                                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                                int hour = picker.getCurrentHour();
                                                int minute = picker.getCurrentMinute();
                                                onDateSelectedListener.onDateSelected(s + " " + hour + ":" + minute);
                                            }
                                        })
                                        .setNegativeButton("One way", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                                dialog.dismiss();
                                            }
                                        }).create().show();
                            }
                        }
                )
                .setNegativeButton("One way", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .create().show();
    }

    public interface OnDateSelectedListener{
        public void onDateSelected(String date);
    }

}
```

Now call DateTimePicker with OnDateSelectedListener reference :

```
DateTimePicker dateTimePicker = new DateTimePicker();
dateTimePicker.returnDate(this.getActivity(), new DateTimePicker.OnDateSelectedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDateSelected(String date) {
      leaving.setText(st);
   }
});
```