# How can I write a method to make this code reuseable?

Tags: java, javafx

I have the following code where the  `Binding.createStringBinding(...)` part is going to be repeated many many times, the only difference is the method used, i.e. `getA()`, `getB()` , `getC()`

```
    this.attributeA.bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
        if(webService.getLastValue() != null){
            return webService.getLastValue().getA();
        } else{
            return "";
        }
    }, webService.lastValueProperty()));

    this.attributeB.bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
        if(webService.getLastValue() != null){
            return webService.getLastValue().getB();
        } else{
            return "";
        }
    }, webService.lastValueProperty()));
```

**New:**
This is the part of the code that I want to make reusable:

```
Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
            if(webService.getLastValue() != null){
                return webService.getLastValue().getB();
            } else{
                return "";
            }
        }, webService.lastValueProperty())
```

How can I make this reusable? Perhaps making this a function ?

Comment: other difference is `this.attributeA` or `B` or `C`, I assume

Comment: there is a confusion. I updated my question slightly.

Comment: What type is `webService.getLastValue()` returning?

Comment: It returns an object, say `ObjectTest`, and method `getA` is in this `ObjectTest`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
private Binding createBinder(final Supplier<String> lambda) {
    return Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
        if(webService.getLastValue() != null){
            return lambda.get();
        } else{
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

called like

```
this.attributeA.bind(createBinder(() -> webService.getLastValue().getA()), webService.lastValueProperty());
this.attributeB.bind(createBinder(() -> webService.getLastValue().getB()), webService.lastValueProperty());
```

Comment: There is an error in the parameter `lambda`, `Syntax error, insert "... VariableDeclaratorId" to complete FormalParameterList`

Comment: As I said, the data type is not correct because i couldn't recall it. I wanted you to find it because you should be able to invest some work yourself. I'll update my answer though.

Comment: So with the `Supplier` interface, we pass method as parameter without separately creating an interface mentioned in these answers  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186931/java-pass-method-as-parameter?

Comment: Exactly. The `Supplier` interface belongs to the JDK 8 and it's sole purpose is to provide a mapping for certain lambda expressions.

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation on @Joshua's answer. Here `ObjectTest` is the type returned by `webService.getLastValue()`.

```
private void makeBinding(StringProperty property, Function<ObjectTest, String> propertyAccessor) {
   property.bind( Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
        ObjectTest lastValue = webService.getLastValue();
        if (lastValue == null) {
            return "" ;
        } else return propertyAccessor.apply(lastValue);
    }, webService.lastValueProperty()) );
}
```

And now you do

```
makeBinding(attributeA, ObjectTest::getA);
makeBinding(attributeB, ObjectTest::getB);
```

etc

Comment: Why did we have `property` as a parameter, if it is not used in the method? And my properties are all `ReadOnlyStringWrapper` s

Comment: Sorry, got caught between two different versions of what I intended.  See update. `ReadOnlyStringWrapper` is a subclass of `StringProperty`, so this should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose `attributeA` and `attributeB` both implement the `Property<String>` interface, and that methods `getA`, `getB`, etc. all return a `String`. With this in mind, you could do:

```
BiConsumer<Property<String>, Function<ObjectTest, String>> binder = 
    (property, getter) ->
        property.bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
            if (webService.getLastValue() != null) {
                return getter.apply(webService.getLastValue());
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        }, webService.lastValueProperty()));
```

This code creates a `BiConsumer` (which is a consumer that takes 2 arguments).

The first argument is an instance of `Property<String>` (as suggested by @James_D's comment) that is implemented by `attributeA` and `attributeB`.

The second argument is a `Function<ObjectTest, String>`, which is a function that takes an instance of `ObjectTest` and returns a `String`. Here I'm using it to represent a generic getter method over the `ObjectTest` class (more specifically, `ObjectTest::getA` and `ObjectTest::getB`).

If you want, you could rewrite the `BiConsumer' in a more java8 friendly way:

```
BiConsumer<Property<String>, Function<ObjectTest, String>> binder = 
    (property, getter) ->
        property.bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(
            () -> Optional.ofNullable(webService.getLastValue())
                .map(getter).orElse(""),
            webService.lastValueProperty()));
```

To use it:

```
binder.accept(this.attributeA, ObjectTest::getA);
binder.accept(this.attributeB, ObjectTest::getB);
```

The code above assumes that methods `getA`, `getB`, etc. return a `String`.

You might want to further read about [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) and [`BiConsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html) in the javadocs.

Comment: I assume the interface in question is actually [`Property<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/Property.html). (I like the use of `Optional` though.)

Comment: @James_D I don't know anything about javafx, thanks for the input.