# Execute a task for a given time if fails

Tags: java, spring-boot, timer, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to create a service that will be able to execute some task (a method) and retry it that task fails.

For creating timers I am using a **timer service** with quartz (*I am not able to change the timer service*).

**Timer service** has method

```
this.timerService.createTimerRunRepeatedly(
            handledId,
            timerId,
            optionalDescription,
            totalFireCount,
            intervalMiliSeconds,
            offsetMiliseconds,
            optionalCallbackData);
```

It is also able to register a handler for created timer.

```
this.timerService.registerHandler(
                  handlerId,
                  firedCallback,
                  expiredCallback);
```

**firedCallback** -> (optional) callback that is called each time a timer with this handler fires (`final Consumer<T> firedCallback`)

**expiredCallback** -> (optional) callback that is called after a timer with this handler has fired the last time (`final Consumer<T> expiredCallback`)

I have created a new **TaskRetryService** but I have no idea how can I pass some method to this retryService for it to be executed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186931/java-pass-method-as-parameter Was this the question you were asking?

Comment: It is similar, yes. I will take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I managed to make it work since I had everything I needed. Just registered a handler

```
 @PostConstruct
 public void onPostConstruct() {
    handler = this.retryService.registerHandler("1", this::fireCallback, this::expiredCallback);
 }
```

Callbacks are

```
private <T> void fireCallback(final T t) {
    System.out.println("fireCallback");
}
private <T> void expiredCallback(final T t) {
    System.out.println("expiredCallback");
}
```

And created timer with

```
this.retryService.retryTask(handler, "12", 1, 5);
```

In retry service I have

```
public void retryTask(final HandlerId<String> handlerId,
                      final String timerId,
                      final Integer intervalTimeMinutes,
                      final Integer retryTimeMinutes) {
    this.timerService.createTimerRunRepeatedly(handlerId,
            timerId,
            "timer",
            getTotalFireCount(intervalTimeMinutes, retryTimeMinutes),
            (int) TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(intervalTimeMinutes),
            0,
            null).thenAccept(timerWasCreated -> {
        if (timerWasCreated) {
            System.out.println("Timer was created");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error while creating timer");
        }
    });
}
```

And

```
public <T> HandlerId<T> registerHandler(final String handlerId,
                                        final Consumer<T> firedCallback,
                                        final Consumer<T> expiredCallback) {
    return this.timerService.registerHandler(handlerId, firedCallback, expiredCallback);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Spring consider using [`Spring-Retry`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry) which  has out-of-box feature(s) to handle failure and retry.

By annotating method with `@Retryable(SomeException.class)` the method will be retried when `SomeException` is raised. It can be further customized to specify the retry attempts, delays (*random & exponential*) between attempts as `@Retryable(maxAttempts=12, backoff=@Backoff(delay=100, maxDelay=500))`

For failure callback `@Recover` annotated method will be invoked.

For more implementation notes check the [readme](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry) at github and [this](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry) article.

Hope this helps!