# Any Method into Parameterlist?

Tags: java, methods, parameters

I have a problem, that I want to solve, but I dont have the knowledge to do it yet.

Is there a possibility I can put any Method into the parameter list anytime?

For Example:

```
public void goThroughArray(anyMethod()){
for (int i = 0; i<array.length;i++){
    anyMethod();
}

public int[] copyArray(int[]arrayName2){
 arrayName1[i] = arrayName2[i];
}

//in main
goThroughArray(copyArray(int[]arrayName);
```

Is that possible?

Comment: A lambda would be the closest to what you're looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Pass Method as Parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186931/java-pass-method-as-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass [`Function<T, R>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) as a parameter to other method in Java 8,

```
public void goThroughArray(Function<int[], int[]> myFunction){
   int[] resultArray = myFunction.apply(anyArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it is possible if you are using java 8(1.8).**

You can use `interface Function<T,R>` to achieve your whatever thing.

From Oracle:

> Type Parameters:
>
> T - the type of the input to the function
>
> R - the type of the result of the function
>
> All Known Subinterfaces:
>       UnaryOperator
>
> Functional Interface:
>
> This is a functional interface and can therefore be used as the assignment target for a lambda expression or method reference.

Learn more:

- [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html)
- [Javabrahman](http://www.javabrahman.com/java-8/java-8-java-util-function-function-tutorial-with-examples/)