# Java, Android: Passing a promise in a callback function

Tags: java, android, callback, promise

In my code I am trying to pass a function as a parameter.

The function has two arguments: a promise, and an int. I want to pass the promise with the parameter, and the int will be set by the child function.

```
public void getUser(final Promise promise) {

    UserHelper.saveMe(getReactApplicationContext(), callBack(promise, int myInt));

}

public void callBack(Promise promise, int myInt){
    if (user != null) {
        promise.resolve(doSomething(myInt));
    }
}
```

Child Function

```
public static void saveMe(Context context, function callBack) {

    **some code here

    returnUser(20);

}
```

I have done similar things in JS and PHP before, but I can't figure out how to run in Java.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can't pass a method (not function) in Java. For alternative, read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186931/java-pass-method-as-parameter

Comment: Is there any way to implement this without using an interface? I mean having the promise executed when the child function is complete? I tried passing the promise as a parameter, but the app crashes when it gets to that point.