# Creating a reference to a function and passing as a parameter to a local method (Java)

Tags: java, function, pointers

A class has a reference to another instance (autowired via Spring)

```
public class Instance1 {
    public void m1(String args) {
        System.out.println(arg);
    }
    public void m2(String args) {
        System.out.println(arg);
    }
    public void m3(String args) {
        System.out.println(arg);
    }
}

public class process() {

@AutoWire
    public Instance1 instance1

    public void processA() {
        // Get a reference to m1, m2, or m3
        processB(<pass referrnce here>);
    }
    public void processB(<accept reference to m1, m2 , m3 here>) {
        // Call either m1, m2, or m3
    }
}
```

That instance includes 3 methods, let's say m1, m2 and m3. I want to be able to set a reference to each of those methods and pass it as a parameter to another local method, which will call either m1, m2 and m3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Pass Method as Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186931/java-pass-method-as-parameter)

Comment: Could you explain why you want to/have to do it this way? It sounds like a case for polymorphism or lambdas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) for each method:

```
public void processA() {
    processB(instance1::m1, instance1::m2, instance1::m3);
}

public void processB(Consumer<String> c1, Consumer<String> c2, Consumer<String> c3) {
    c1.accept("Arg");
    c2.accept("Arg");
    c3.accept("Arg");
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ruslan, Let me give this a try; I'll let you know on Tuesday!

Comment: Instantiated an instance of Instance1 in static main and it worked:
   Instance1 instance1 = new Instance1();
   processB(instance1::m1, instance1::m2, instance1::m3);