# How can I pass a method to a constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

I have my class A with the following methods.

```
class A{
    public A(){}
    public void methodA(){}
    public void methodB(){}
    public instantiateObject(){
        Object objectA= new Object();
        Object objectB = new Object();

    }
```

}

And my class Object:

```
class Object{
    public Object(){}
    public void receivedMethod(){}
```

}

Now I want, that objectA receives methodA() and objectB receives methodB(). So in receivedMethod in objectA should use methodA and in objectB  methodB(). What can I do so that either receive the right method? Can I somehow give class Object in the constructor a method? Like you would do it with variables?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Pass Method as Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186931/java-pass-method-as-parameter)

Comment: That exactly answers my question. Thank you!

Comment: I'm hoping that you aren't calling any class you make Object, because that will cause all sorts of bugs.

Comment: Nope @NomadMaker, i just called it that way here as I should not publish private information of my program