# How to pass a method invocation to a method (Java 8)

Tags: java, methods, parameter-passing, refactoring, dry

My original code looked like this:

```
SpecificEntity result = broker.changeSpecificEntity ( myTestKey , myTestData ) ;
```

"broker" is an (interface/implementation facade) with several methods (create, change, remove, etc) for each of many entity types.

I want to implement a generic version of the code so I don't have to repeat myself.  There is more code than shown here, but the rest is already generic.

This is what we have so far.

```
public < K extends Key , D extends Data > D changeAnyEntity ( final K testKey, final D testData, BiFunction<K, D, D> brokerMethod ) 
{
    return brokerMethod.apply ( testKey , testData ) ;
}
```

Now I need to invoke a generic method, (e.g., changeAnyEntity) for each of the methods under test.

```
SpecificEntity result = changeAnyEntity ( myTestKey , myTestData , myBrokerFuncion )
```

I have not yet figured out how to define / create "myBrokerFunction"

Comment: Frequently the answer to "how do I pass a method" is to declare a method that accepts an interface that includes the signature of the method that you want to call. Ideally, it's a @FunctionalInterface, to make it easy to pass lambdas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass Method as Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186931/).

Comment: I re-wrote the question to clarify where I am at.  The help provided so far moved me along, but I'm still stuck on how to tie it all together.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface with a single method accepting your wanted arguments and returning the type you need.
Then you can use that interface as a parameter type, and you can avoid all unnecessary casting inside your generic method. The reason for making it generic is to avoid "knowing" about all individual child types after all

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface BrokerFun<KK, DD> {
    DD changeEntity(KK key, DD data);
}

public < K extends Key , D extends Data > boolean changeAnything (
        final K testKey,
        final D testData,
        BrokerFun<K, D> brokerFun
) {
    try {
        D result = brokerFun.changeEntity(testKey,testData);
        return isEqualCriticalFields(result, testData);
    } catch ( final Exception e ) {
        return false ;
    }
}
```

**EDIT(Adding a BiFunction solution)**

Alternatively you can use the BiFunction interface like this

```
public < K extends Key , D extends Data > boolean changeAnything (
        final K testKey,
        final D testData,
        BiFunction<K, D, D> brokerFun
) {
    try {
        D result = brokerFun.apply(testKey,testData);
        return isEqualCriticalFields(result, testData);
    } catch ( final Exception e ) {
        return false ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks -- I'll take another look -- my comment above (apparently with lousy markdown) shows where I'm currently stuck.

Comment: Ok I see you wanna use BiFunction, let me add to my answer

Comment: I have added a BiFunction solution. You don't need to declare another generic type for your Interface, I think that's where you are getting confused.
The BiFunction or the declared Interface should use the types of the other arguments, K and D are the only generic types you need. This way you will make sure that this function cannot be called with incompatible types

Comment: You're right about me being confused, but it looks as though you've done what I was aiming for (not that I care whether I use BiFunction or not -- I just want something that works and doesn't smell ;-) )

It's getting late (for January 1st) so I'll probably continue tomorrow.  I think I'm still missing the part where I supply the broker function 

changeAnything ( myTestKey , myTestData , myBrokerFunction )

where originally the broker function was "broker.changeEntity"

Answer (score 0):

Finally . . . ignoring try/catch logic

```
final BiFunction < SpecificEntityKey , SpecificEntityData , SpecificEntityData >
brokerMethod = ( k , d ) -> { myBroker.changeSpecificEntity ( k , d , null ) ; return d ; } ;
```

Comment: and of course, by defining my own interface instead of using BiFunction, I was able to include the necessary throws declaration and everything works perfectly.  Thank you both.  I can't @ both of you for some reason!  @AndyThomas

Comment: Thank you both. I can't @ both of you for some reason! @KlitosG