# C# delegate function implementation in Java

Tags: java, c#-4.0, delegates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Delegates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912/java-delegates)

What is the replacment of Delegate function of C# in Java. How to convert this in Java. I am using Delegate function in C# project needs to be implemented in Java version of the same project. How to resolve this issues. please help.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912/java-delegates

Comment: I tried with the same articles but was unable to clear my concept and getting the desired result. Please have some code snippet by taking some small delegate function or lyk ways. I tried from the same articles.