# Saving Array Data

Tags: java, android

i have problem to save my arraylist. I want to save my arraylist when application destroy or change intent or change orientation:

```
public class AuditContainer implements Serializable {
    private Paint mPaint;
    private Path mPath;
    private int x,y;
    private String text;
    boolean is_text;
```

First i tried saving in file, but Paint class isn't Serializable class. 
Second i try with onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) / onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) but i could not save Arraylist
and third i try with database but there isnt any types of Paint, Path ...
If anyone have got suggestion for me, i will be very happy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three choices:

A. Modify `Paint` to implement [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com//6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).
B. Mark the field as not for serialization using the [`transient`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.3) keyword:

```
private transient Paint mPaint;
```

C. Write your own Serializable wrapper for Paint that keeps Serializable copies of the key fields, and [delegates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_%28programming%29) functionality to a private transient Paint, and can re-initialize the Paint instance after deserialization.

Comment: Problem is if i use first option, i have got problem and java trow exception java.io.WriteAbortedException: Read an exception; java.io.NotSerializableException: android.graphics.Paint. if i use second option paint and path class are null :(

Comment: Check out the new third option

Comment: Problem is java has not have delegate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912/java-delegates

Comment: Are you think it will be better if i use the database and maybe if use function to arraylist<AuditContainer>.getindex(0) change to string and i save it ...

Answer (score 3):

If `Paint` and `Path` are classes under your control, then make them serializable too.  If they are not completely relevant or you can determine them externally when you read the object back, then you can make the fields `transient`.

Answer (score 1):

To omit the serialization of non-serializable fields, mark them as `transient`:

```
public class AuditContainer implements Serializable {
    private transient Paint mPaint;
    private transient Path mPath;
    private int x,y;
    private String text;
    boolean is_text;
}
```

Probably there's data on `Paint mPaint` and `Path mPath` fields that you still want to store on serialization and retrieve on deserialization processes, for this you have to implement `writeObject` and `readObject` methods:

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out)
    throws IOException {
    //default serialization of the object
    out.defaultWriteObject();
    //start manual serialization
    out.writeInt(mPaint.getX());
    out.writeInt(mPaint.getY());
    out.writeObject(mPath.getPath());
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in)
    throws IOException {
    //default serialization of the object
    in.defaultReadObject();
    //start manual deserialization
    int x = in.readInt();
    int y = in.readInt();
    String path = (String)in.readObject();
    //initialize your fields...
    //note: this code maybe won't work, you should adapt it to your needs
    mPaint = new Paint(x, y);
    mPath = new Path(path);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use third party like XStream.It allows use to save object to xml, and it not need that object must be Serializable. We had similair problem in our company (class that cannot be modified and must be saved) and XStream helped us.
Please look at: http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html for simple tutorial.