# Difference between passing a delegate and an interface?

Tags: c#, delegates

Are there any major differences between passing a delegate and passing an interface to a method? I see the c# delegate as a "method interface". In this perspective, there is no difference between passing a delegate and passing a thin interface with only one method. I  try to make small interfaces (SRP), so I always regarded delegates as somewhat redundant. But am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delegates can, indeed, be seen as interfaces/contracts for a single method and are thus similar to interfaces. The main difference between them is in the language syntax, especially support for anonymous methods and (since C# 3.0) lambdas.

If you're creating explicit, named implementations for all your interfaces and delegates, your code would look very similar:

```
var item = myList.FindBySelector(SelectorMethod); // delegate-based;
var item = myList.FindBySelector(new MySelectorImpl()); // interface-based.
```

However, if you're going for anonymous types, it can get a lot messier with interfaces - consider this example from C# vs. one from Java 7, which supports anonymous types but not anonymous methods:

```
var item = myList.FindBySelector(new SelectorDelegate(item => item.IsTheOne));
```

vs.

```
Item item = myList.FindBySelector(new ISelector () 
{
   @Override
   public boolean apply(Item item) 
   {
       return item.IsTheOne;
   }
});
```

So if you're jumping down the rabbit hole of anonymous methods, using delegates makes a lot more sense, since you're dealing with *only* the method interface, without the class interface cruft around it.

Comment: And in particular, C# took this particular route (as opposed to the anonymous class approach in Java), and so you _have_ to use delegates where you don't want to have to create a whole new named type. C#'s delegate type inference makes use of delegates very easy and fluent, making it a superior choice to interfaces where appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

A single-method interface is pretty much identical in power to a delegate. Of course you need one derived class for each "method" that you want to pass.

From an implementation standpoint the two are very similar. The delegate stores a function pointer. The interface object reference has a function pointer in it's vtable.

I believe [a recent Java version implements lambdas with single-method interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311779/is-there-delegate-in-java-8-jdk8).