# Java Delegate Interface

Tags: java, lambda, interface

Is there a simple Interface in Java like the following code?

```
public interface Delegate {
    void action();
}
```

[Java Delegates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912/java-delegates) describes the functionality well.
It's not a Supplier, not a Consumer, not a Function, not a Runnable(no async stuff needed), I just want to pass a lambda to a method to be executed in between common parts.

Now I'm wondering why I have to define this interface myself. Am I just unable to find the standard Java interface for this or am I missing some vital drawback here?

Usage in my code (simplified):

```
public void transferX(Xrequest request){
  transfer(request, () -> this.typedWrite(request));
}
public void transferY(Yrequest request){
  transfer(request, () -> this.typedWrite(request));
}
void transfer(BaseRequest request, final Delegate writeFunction){
  ...
  try{
    writeFunction.action();
    ...
  catch(...){...}
}
void typedWrite(Xrequest request){...}
void typedWrite(Yrequest request){...}
```

Comment: Why is it not a `Runnable`? How is async related?

Comment: Hmm you're right. Doc states "The Runnable interface should be implemented by any class whose instances are intended to be executed by a thread", but it's actually the same.

Comment: What do you mean `but it's actually the same.`

Comment: See answer below, the code matches, meaning I can just use Runnable instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, as Sweeper pointed out, that is just the Runnable interface. I just don't like the naming, since I immediately associate it with multithreading.

For comparison:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Runnable {
    public abstract void run();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the naming comes from before the introduction of functional interfaces, so they kept it.