# handle methods in a class calling shared sub-methods with varying order and frequency in Java/Kotlin

Tags: java, design-patterns

How can I implement multiple methods in a Java/Kotlin class that invoke the same sub-methods but in a different order, or sometimes a method calls more sub-methods than another? Is there a design pattern for this scenario?

```
                  +------------------+
                  |   My Class       |
                  +------------------+
                           |
            +--------------+--------------+
            |                             |
 +------------------+         +------------------+
 | Method A         |         | Method B         |
 +------------------+         +------------------+
 | Call SubMethod 1 |         | Call SubMethod 2 |
 | Call SubMethod 2 |         | Call SubMethod 1 |
 | ...              |         | ...              |
 +------------------+         +------------------+
                

  +------------------+         +------------------+
  | SubMethod 1      |         | SubMethod 2      |
  +------------------+         +------------------+
  | Implementation   |         | Implementation   |
  | ...              |         | ...              |
  +------------------+         +------------------+
```

I have a lot of methods to implement on the same class.

Answer (score 1):

If it's only a couple of methods, I wouldn't overthink it, and just hardcode the calls:

```
public class MyClass {
    public void subMethod1() {/* ... */}
    public void subMethod2() {/* ... */}
   
    public void methodA() {
        subMethod1();
        subMethod2();
    }

    public void methodB() {
        subMethod2();
        subMethod1();
    }
}
```

Or, in other words - don't over-engineer where you don't have to.

Comment: thank you for your response. Ihave at least 12 methods .

Comment: Is there any logic behind their order? If it's just mixing and matching without some more concise definition, I feat there's not a lot you can do.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar and do not have an IDE with Java, but I  would like to share with idea how it is possible to run methods in order that you want.

The following code is using C# and I found a link how you can [imitate delegates in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912/java-delegates). Basically, what you need is just an array where you add your references to your method in a desired order.

So the complete code would look like this.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void RunInYourOrder(IEnumerable<Action> someMethodsInYourDesiredOrder) 
    {
        foreach (var method in someMethodsInYourDesiredOrder)
        {
            method?.Invoke();
        }
    }

    public void Method1() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method 1 is called");
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method 2 is called");
    }
}
```

And code to run would look like this:

```
MyClass myClass= new MyClass();
List<Action> methodsToBeRun = new List<Action>()
{ 
    () => myClass.Method2(),
    () => myClass.Method1(),
};
myClass.RunInYourOrder(methodsToBeRun);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Method 2 is called
Method 1 is called
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define the steps as Consumers which could be directly referenced and in the consumer of this method you could define the order.

```
class Scratch {

    private static final Consumer<TaskDoer> task5 = buildable1 -> buildable1.task5(5);
    private static final Consumer<TaskDoer> task1 = buildable1 -> buildable1.task1();
    private static final Consumer<TaskDoer> task2 = buildable1 -> buildable1.task2();
    private static final Consumer<TaskDoer> task3 = buildable1 -> buildable1.task3();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TaskOrganizer organizer = new TaskOrganizer();
        TaskDoer doer = new TaskDoer();//your class

        organizer.addSteps(task1,task3,task1,task5,task2);
        organizer.build(doer);
        System.out.println(doer.outResult);
    }
}
class TaskOrganizer {
    
    TaskDoer taskDoer;
    
    List<Consumer<TaskDoer>> orderOfSteps = new ArrayList<Consumer<TaskDoer>>();

    public void addStep(Consumer<TaskDoer> task){
        orderOfSteps.add(task);
    }

    public void addSteps(Consumer<TaskDoer> ... steps){
        for (int i = 0; i < steps.length; i++) {
            orderOfSteps.add(steps[i]);
        }
    }


    public void build(TaskDoer buildable) {
        for (Consumer<TaskDoer> r:orderOfSteps) {
            r.accept(buildable);
        }
    }
}
class TaskDoer {
    String outResult="";
    
    public void task1(){
        outResult = outResult+" task1";
    }
    public void task2(){
        outResult = outResult+" task2";
    }
    public void task3(){
        outResult = outResult+" task3";
    }
    public void task4(){
        outResult = outResult+" task4";
    }

    public void task5(int i) {
        outResult = outResult+" task5";
    }
}
```